# Integral $\int _{\partial D}\frac{4z+\pi}{(e^{4iz}+1)\cos2z}$ with Residues.

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, residue-calculus

I have to calculate the following integral using Th of residues:

> $$ \int _{\partial D}\frac{4z+\pi}{(e^{4iz}+1)\cos2z}$$ 
>   where $D=\{z \in  C : |z|<1\}$.

I find a pole in $\pi/4$. The problem is that I don't manage to classify the order of this pole. Wolfram says that it  is a second order pole, but to verify it I should calculate the
$$\lim _{z\to\pi/4} {(z-\pi/4)}^2 \frac{4z+\pi}{(e^{4iz}+1)\cos2z} $$
that I don't know how to solve.The other option is to calculate the Laurent series  around the point $\pi/4 $ and calculate the term   $ a_{-1} $ . Someone has an idea about how can I do?
Thank you for the attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have\begin{align}\lim _{z\to\frac\pi4}{\left(z-\frac\pi4\right)}^2\frac{4z+\pi}{(e^{4iz}+1)\cos2z}&=\lim_{z\to\frac\pi4}\frac{4z+\pi}{\dfrac{e^{4i z}+1}{z-\frac\pi4}\times\dfrac{\cos(2z)}{z-\frac\pi4}}\\&=\frac{2\pi}{4ie^{\pi i}\times\left(-2\sin\left(\frac\pi2\right)\right)}\\&=\frac{2\pi}{8 i}\\&=-\frac{\pi i}4.\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

The pole $z=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ is of order $2$, so you must obtain
$$\operatorname{Res}_{z=\dfrac{\pi}{4}}\dfrac{4z+\pi}{(e^{4iz}+1)\cos2z}=\lim_{z\to\dfrac{\pi}{4}} \dfrac{d}{dz}\left((z-\dfrac{\pi}{4})^2\dfrac{4z+\pi}{(e^{4iz}+1)\cos2z}\right)$$
for simplicity let $z-\dfrac{\pi}{4}=w$ and 
$$(z-\dfrac{\pi}{4})^2\dfrac{4z+\pi}{(e^{4iz}+1)\cos2z}=\dfrac{w^2(4w+2\pi)}{2ie^{2iw}\sin^22w}$$
so find 
$$\lim_{w\to0}\dfrac{d}{dw}\dfrac{w^2(4w+2\pi)}{2ie^{2iw}\sin^22w}$$

Comment: Thanks very much...you're great

Comment: Even if  i find that $\cos(2z)= cos(2(w+\pi/4))=cos(2w+\pi/2)=- \sin(2w)$